# data from droplist to database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need advice, what i did wrong and this code not working. In short I have droplist menu with data read from mysql database and I want this data what user selected put in to another table/row in db. with present code I received only NULL value in inserted row... some I assume maybe something wrong with syntax, I tried search similar topic and tried different way but result is same :| This is my code :

get function and form

```
   <br><br>
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';
$sql="select * from persons";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $id=$row["id"]; 
    $name=$row["name"]; 
    $name_done.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$name; 
} 

?>  
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<SELECT name="name_done" id="nane_done"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose Your name : 
<?=$name_done?> 
</SELECT> <br>
RFC: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And Insert

```
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';

$name_done = $_POST['nane_done'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO rfc(name_done) VALUES (.$name_done)");

---- below working OK----

$sql = "INSERT INTO rfc(number,date) 
VALUES
('$_POST[number]','$_POST[date]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql,$name_done))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "RFC added";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You need to close <option> & <select> tags, and what's the dot in query: (.$name_done)? Also end all <input> tags with '/>'. And in your php script you get $_POST['nane_done'], but in html name of your select is 'name_done'.

Comment: It is a bad idea to get info directly from POST without checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo - "nane_done" rather than "name_done" in this line: `$name_done = $_POST['nane_done'];`.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I looking on this code and i not noticed ;) nane ;)

Comment: You look at the code so often you go blind to things like this, but other people can spot it within seconds. It's happened to everybody!